# SELECT the min time for each bus stop

Tags: sql, sqlite, time, min

I have a table with columns time_id, bus_id, stop_id and time. Like this:

```
time_id |bus_id     | stop_id     | time
1       |19         | 51          | 00:08:00
2       |19         | 51          | 00:09:00
3       |19         | 51          | 00:10:00
4       |19         | 12          | 00:08:30
5       |19         | 12          | 00:09:30
6       |19         | 12          | 00:10:30
7       |23         | 31          | 00:08:00
8       |23         | 31          | 00:09:00
9       |23         | 31          | 00:10:00
10      |23         | 42          | 00:08:30
11      |23         | 42          | 00:09:30
12      |23         | 42          | 00:10:30
```

I want rows with the min(time) for each group of (bus_id and stop_id). Like this:

```
time_id |bus_id | stop_id     | time
1       |19     | 51          | 00:08:00
4       |19     | 12          | 00:08:30
7       |23     | 31          | 00:08:00
10      |23     | 42          | 00:08:30
```

Any help would be great. Using SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard SQL to do this is:

```
SELECT bus_id, stop_id, MIN(time) as time
FROM tablename
GROUP BY bus_id, stop_id
ORDER BY bus_id, stop_id
```

This will return the minimum value from the time field for each combination of bus and stop ID. I've also sorted the results using an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: yup that worked like a charm...group by is new to me and this awesome so thanks a lot!